# Некорректно отображается кириллица в SQL запросе filter() в R

Tags: sql, r, rstudio

Есть запрос вида `kia <- sspi %>% filter(org = "Киа Краснодар") %>% collect()`
Выдает такую ошибку:

```
Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1655: 42000: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Неправильный синтаксис около ключевого слова "AS".  [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Не удалось выполнить подготовку инструкций. 
<SQL> 'SELECT *
FROM "SSP_indicators"
WHERE ('РљРёР° РљСЂР°СЃРЅРѕРґР°СЂ' AS "org")'
```

Обратите внимание на последнюю строчку. Рльёх. Ктулху Фтаъгн.

Пробовал:

- сохранять скрипт в разных кодировках
- использовать пункт меню `файл` > `открыть в другой кодировке`

УПД: Я по-другому решил этот фильтр, но конкретно в этом выражении проблема в отсутствии двойного знака равенства после org. Всем спасибо.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: ругается то он не на кириллицу вашу, а на вобоще это выражение `'xxx' as "org"` в `where`

Comment: Так предложите, как фильтровать.

Comment: Если Вам нужен фильтр, то 'SELECT * FROM SSP_indicators org = "Киа Краснодар"'


В общем виде:  your_connection %>% tbl(sql('SELECT * FROM SSP_indicators org = "Киа Краснодар"')) %>% as.data.frame()